# Android List show checkbox with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

How to do like this,any solution,thanks?
[image: First]
[image: Then]

Comment: idk lol what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried to use swipelayout to do,but have bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutTransition can do it perfect,but recyclerview should call notifyItemRangeChanged